# Recurrence relation using substitution method

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, substitution

How do I solve the following recurrence using substitution method?

$$T(n) = T(n-1)+C$$

I've found reference to so many examples on line but most of the examples are of the form

$$T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + n$$

So, I am really struggling to understand it and to solve $T(n) = T(n-1)+C$ using substitution method.

I appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start substituting, we have
\begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-1) + C
\end{align*}
Now, we use this again, but for $n-1$ instead of $n$, that is
\begin{align*}
  T(n-1) &= T(n-2) + C
\end{align*}
Combining both, we get
\begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-1) + C\\
       &= T(n-2) + C + C\\
       &= T(n-2) + 2C
\end{align*}
Now, apply the recursion for $n-2$, giving
\begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-2) + 2C\\
       &= T(n-3) + 3C
\end{align*}
The pattern should now be clear. Having applied the recursion $k$ times, we have 
\begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-{\color{red} k}) + {\color{red} k}C\\
\end{align*}
That is, for $k=n$
$$ T(n) = T(0) + nC $$

Comment: Thanks @martini pretty simple and well explained